# avr-gcc: icall implementation in C++

Tags: avr-gcc

I would like to know how to implement AVR ICALL instruction in the C++ scope. Let say I have a pointer variable that holds the address of my function and I want another function to call the function indirectly through the pointer kept in the variable.

Thanks in advance for the help and assistance.

Comment: [You mean this?](https://godbolt.org/z/bre9f7Ph6)

Answer (score 0):

You just pass the function pointer as an argument to the function and then call it as usual:

```cpp
int call_pf (int (*pf)(int))
{
    return pf (1);
}
```

Sometimes, people find that syntax of function pointer declaration confusing, and they use a typedef if possible:

```cpp
typedef int (*func_t)(int);

using fun_p = int (*)(int); // C++ only
```

and then use `func_t` or `fun_p` as usual:

```cpp
int call2_pf (func_t pf)
{
    return pf (2);
}
```

To get the address of a function, just use its name without argument(s):

```cpp
int inc (int i)
{
    return i + 1;
}

int main (void)
{
    return call1_pf (inc) + call2_pf (inc);
}
```

Depending on the context and controller, avr-gcc may use `icall`, `eicall`, `ijmp`, `eijmp` or a `push/push/ret` sequence to implement the indirect (tail) call.  When the compiler can work out the function address at compile time, it may transform the indirect call to a direct one.

---

In C++, when taking the address of a non-static method, then in order to call it an object of the appropriate type is needed to perform the indirect method invocation, and operator `->*` or `.*` must be used for that:

```cpp
struct S
{
    int s;
    int meth (int i) const { return s + i; }
};

int fun_S (const S *s, int (S::*fun)(int) const)
{
    return (s ->* fun) (1);
}

int fun_S (const S &s, int (S::*fun)(int) const)
{
    return (s .* fun) (1);
}

int call_fun_S (const S &s)
{
    return fun_S (s, &S::meth) + fun_S (&s, &S::meth);
}
```